# How does $H_1$ change after projection

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, complex-geometry

Suppose $X\subset \mathbb{CP}^N$ is a $n$ dimensional projective manifold (and complex dimension $n>1$), take a general projection $p\colon X\to\mathbb{CP}^{n+1}$. Suppose $H_1(X)$ is nontravial. Does it hold $H_1(p(X))$ is nontrivial?

(It would show the smoothness condition on the ample divisor in Lefschetz hyperplane theorem is necessary)

Comment: $H_1$ is trivial for any hypersurface  $Z\subset\mathbb{P}^{n+1}$ ($n\geq 2$), singular or not. See for instance Milnor's *Morse Theory*, corollary 7.3 (observe that $Z$ can be realized as a hyperplane section of the Veronese embedding of degree $\deg(Z)$ of $\mathbb{P}^{n+1}$).

Comment: @abx: You beat me to it.  I gave a very explicit example.  I thought that might be more convincing to a beginner than Morse theory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not true, and you can make counterexamples by considering projections of projective bundles over a curve. Let $C$ be a smooth, projective curve.  Let $n\geq 5$ be an integer.  Let $X$ be $C\times \mathbb{P}^{n-1}$.  Let $\mathcal{L}_C$ be a very ample invertible sheaf on $C$, and denote $H^0(C,\mathcal{L}_C)$ by $V_C$.  For every closed point $t$ in $C$, there is an associated surjective linear transformation, $$\text{ev}_t:V_C \to \mathcal{L}_{C,t},$$ where $\mathcal{L}_{C,t}$ is the $1$-dimensional vector space, $$\mathcal{L}_{C,t} = \mathcal{L}\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_C}\mathcal{O}_{C,t}/\mathfrak{m}_{C,t}.$$  Since $\mathcal{L}$ is very ample, for every pair $s$, $t$ of distinct closed points of $C$, the following associated linear transformation is surjective,$$ (\text{ev}_s,\text{ev}_t):V_C \to \mathcal{L}_{C,s}\oplus \mathcal{L}_{C,t}. $$

Denote $H^0(\mathbb{P}^{n-1},\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{n-1}}(1))$ by $V_{\mathbb{P}^{n-1}}$.    Denote by $\mathcal{L}_X$ the invertible sheaf on $X$, $$\mathcal{L}_X = \text{pr}_C^*\mathcal{L}_C\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X} \text{pr}_{\mathbb{P}^{n-1}}\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{n-1}}(1).$$  Denote by $V_X$ the vector space of global sections, $$ V_X = H^0(X,\mathcal{L}_X) = H^0(C,\mathcal{L}_C)\otimes_{\mathbb{C}}H^0(\mathbb{P}^{n-1},\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{n-1}}(1)) = V_C\otimes_{\mathbb{C}}V_{\mathbb{P}^{n-1}}.$$  For every closed point $t$ of $C$, since $\text{ev}_t$ is surjective, also the following linear transformation is surjective, $$\text{ev}_{X,t}: V_X = V_C\otimes_{\mathbb{C}}V_{\mathbb{P}^{n-1}} \to \mathcal{L}_{C,t}\otimes_{\mathbb{C}}V_{\mathbb{P}^{n-1}}.$$ It follows that $\mathcal{L}_X$ is globally generated and there is an induced morphism, $$\phi:X\to \mathbb{P}(V_X^\vee).$$  Moreover, $\mathcal{L}$ is very ample, and for every pair $s$, $t$ of closed points of $C$, since $(\text{ev}_s,\text{ev}_t)$ is surjective, also the following linear transformation is surjective, $$ \text{ev}_{X,s,t} : V_X = V_C\otimes_{\mathbb{C}}V_{\mathbb{P}^{n-1}} \to (\mathcal{L}_{C,s}\oplus \mathcal{L}_{C,t})\otimes_{\mathbb{C}} V_{\mathbb{P}^{n-1}}.$$  It follows that $\mathcal{L}_X$ is very ample and $\phi$ is a closed immersion.

Let $W\subset V_X$ be a linear subspace of dimension $n+2$ parameterized by a point of the complex Grassmannian, $G= \textbf{Grass}(n+2,V_X)$.  There is an associated linear projection, $$ p_W : \mathbb{P}(V_X^\vee)\setminus \mathbb{P}(W^\perp) \to \mathbb{P}(W^\vee). $$  For every closed point $t$ in $C$, since $\text{ev}_{X,t}$ is surjective, there is a Schubert cycle $\Sigma_t$ of codimension $3$ in $G$ parameterizing $W$ such that the codimension $n+2$ subspace $\mathbb{P}(W^\perp)$ has nonempty intersection with the dimension $n-1$ subspace $\phi(\{t\}\times \mathbb{P}^{n-1})$.  There is a subvariety $\Sigma_C$ of $G$ with codimension $2$ that contains every $\Sigma_t$.

Similarly, for every pair of distinct closed points $s$, $t$ of $C$, there is a Schubert subvariety $\Sigma_{s,t}$ of $G$ with codimension $n+1$ parameterizing $W$ such that the induced linear transformation $$ W\hookrightarrow V_X \xrightarrow{\text{ev}_{X,s,t}} (\mathcal{L}_{C,s}\oplus \mathcal{L}_{C,t})\otimes_{\mathbb{C}}V_{\mathbb{P}^{n-1}} $$ has rank $\leq n+1$.  There is a subvariety $\Sigma_{C\times C}$ of $G$ with codimension $n$ that contains every $\Sigma_{s,t}$.  Since $n\geq 1$, there exists $W$ such that the corresponding point of $G$ is not in the closed subset $\Sigma_C$ of codimension $2$, nor is it in the closed subset $\Sigma_{C\times C}$ of codimension $n$.

For such $W$, the closed subset $\mathbb{P}(W^\perp)$ is disjoint from $\phi(X)$.  Moreover, for fixed closed point $s$ of $C$, there is a projective subbundle $Y_s \subset X$ of codimension $2$ such that $p_W(\phi(Y_s))$ is contained in the $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}$, $p_W(\phi(\{s\}\times \mathbb{P}^{n-1}))$.  Thus, there is a commutative diagram of pushforward maps of fundamental groups
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
\pi_1(Y_s) & \to & \pi_1(p_W(\{s\}\times \mathbb{P}^{n-1})) \\
\downarrow & & \downarrow \\
\pi_1(X) & \to & \pi_1(p_W(X))
\end{array}$$
Since the first vertical arrow is an isomorphism, and since $\pi_1(\mathbb{P}^{n-1})$ is trivial, it follows that the bottom horizontal arrow is trivial.

That does not immediately imply that $\pi_1(p_W(X))$ is trivial.  Denote by $U\subset X$ the maximal open subset such that $p_W:U\to p_W(U)$ is an isomorphism.  Let $x$ be a closed point of $U$.  Let $g:Z\to p_W(X)$ be an covering space.  There is a unique structure of complex analytic variety on $Z$ such that $g$ is holomorphic.  Let $z$ be a closed point of $Z$ with $g(z) = x$.  By the previous paragraph, there is a unique holomorphic morphism $h:X\to Z$ such that $g\circ h$ equals $p_W$ and such that $h(x)$ equals $z$.  So the image of $h$ is an irreducible component of $Z$.  Of course if $h(X)$ projects isomorphically to $p_W(X)$, then $g$ is a trivial cover.  Thus assume that $h(X)$ does not project isomorphically to $p_W(X)$.

Since, locally near a general point $p_W(y)$ of $p_W(X\setminus U)$, $p_W(X)$ has two branches, also locally near $h(y)$, $Z$ has two branches.  Using connectedness of the double locus in $p_W(X)$ (every codimension $2$ subvariety of $\mathbb{P}^{n+1}$ is connected if $n\geq 3$), it follows that $Z$ has precisely two irreducible components.  However, since $n\geq 5$, there are also triple points of $p_W(X)$.  This contradiction implies that $g$ is an isomorphism.  Therefore $p_W(X)$ is (topologically) simply connected.  Therefore also $H_1(p_W(X);A)$ is zero for every Abelian group $A$.